# Is subarrayContentToString not exist?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I saw this https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/subarray-content-to-string.html
The usage is stated as

```
fun <T> Array<out T>.subarrayContentToString(
    offset: Int,
    length: Int
): String
```

So I tried

```
val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val s = a.subarrayContentToString(1, 2) // this will error out
```

Did I miss something?
p/s: I'm using Kotlin 1.3

Comment: for Kotlin Native only

Comment: I see, not in JVM (Android Studio).

Comment: Likely it's a helper function mistakenly left public in Kotlin/Native runtime.